# how to get a username and password by email address in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm tryn to get the username and password by email address and send it as a Email [PASSWORD RECOVERY].....
I can check the existance of a user by email but now I need to get the username and password by the email he/she provided before....

here is my DB_Class

```
public boolean getEmail(String emailNo) throws SQLException //pass the EmailNo which you want in where clause 
{                              

Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Username, Passwords FROM " + USERS_TABLE + " WHERE EmailNO='"+emailNo+"'",null); 
 if (mCursor != null) {          
 if(mCursor.getCount() > 0) 
 return true; 

}
return false; 

}
```

And my Activity class for checking user existance and sending email..here is below

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            String EmailAddress = txtEmailAddress.getText().toString();

        try{
        if(EmailAddress.length() > 0)
        {
         DBAdapter  dbUser = new DBAdapter (RecoverPassword.this);
            dbUser.open();

        if(dbUser.getEmailAddress(EmailAddress))
            {
        Toast.makeText(RecoverPassword.this,"Email Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





 String to = txtEmailAddress.getText().toString();

         Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
         email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Password Recovery");

         if(dbUser.getEmail(EmailAddress)){

          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,dbUser.getEmailAddr(obj.getusername(),obj.getpassword())) ;

     }else{

         Toast.makeText(RecoverPassword.this,"Email Not matching " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

      email.setType("message/rfc822");


  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "gmail :"));                 

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(RecoverPassword.this,"Invalid Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        txtEmailAddress.setTex
```

Comment: and what is your question ,debug your self!

Comment: a lot of what you're doing here would be much easier server side. have a look at django/python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never be able to recover a password from your database. If you really want to restore the original password, your security is pretty low (hope you don't store the password as plain text?).

I highly recommend to generate a new one, store it in the database and send it to the user.

After he logs in the first time with the new password you should force him to define a new password. The password itself should be at least salted and hashed. Search for MD5 and salt for more information on that topic. That should be secure enough.

Comment: I need to retrieve a username and password by email Address that all

Comment: Than query your database for the typed in emailadress. Get the username, generate a new password, store it securely in the database and create your email and finally send it. You code in the question is quite confusing and barely readable. Go step by step but consider what I wrote above! Security is important!